# Plot density with ggplot2 without line on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I use `ggplot2::ggplot` for all 2D plotting needs, including density plots, but I find that when plotting a number of overlapping densities with extreme outliers on a single space (in different colors) the line on the x-axis becomes a little distracting.

My question is then, can you remove the bottom section of the density plot from being plotted? If so, how?

You can use this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Should turn out like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about using `stat_density` directly

```
 ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating)) + stat_density(geom="line")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just draw a white line over it:

```
ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating)) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_hline(color = "white", yintercept = 0)
```

[image]